# Develop Java Swing application that can also run a Google App Engine?

Tags: java, swing, google-app-engine, architecture

Mainly brainstorming at this point and after some research, can't really find much about this topic.

I'm designing a Swing app that'll have a database back end for storage, and use the local file-system for of storage BLOBs too. This app isn't going to be CPU, storage, or GUI performance intensive, it's just a specialized database app for electronics project management.

My ideal goal would be to have one codebase that can execute within the JVM and GAE without any changes. I understand the App Engine Datastore is non-relational, so I know I can't use say SQLite for the desktop application. I'd have to go with something like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [Hypertable](http://hypertable.com/).

This program would run locally for 1 to many users and 1 to many users on GAE.

EDIT: Added CRUD requirements.

- Create or add new projects, parts, or BLOBs.
- Read, retrieve, search, or view existing projects, parts, schematics, or any type of BLOB.
- Update/clone or edit existing projects, parts, etc.
- Delete/deactivate existing projects, parts, etc.

Edit 2: In a nutshell, what I'm wondering is this even possible? If you've done a project that could be executed on the desktop or App Engine. I'd like to know what tools, frameworks, libraries, you used; even if you had to use a fully homegrown solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to explain what sort of CRUD and search operations your application needs to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to host an unmodified swing application directly in GAE.

What you can do is have your swing application talk to a [servlet that is deployed to GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime), and handles communication between your swing application and the GAE database.

In the swing application instead of using any database, you would query the servlet for the data. The GAE hosted servlet processes the request, queries the GAE database, encodes the result and streams it back to the client. The swing app receives the response and reacts accordingly. In swing, something like:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/YourApp/YourAction");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    // Server response as stream
    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
} catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
    cpe.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you go this route, remember to always issue your server requests outside the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (easy to do with SwingWorkers).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could not use swing components in GAE, since it is not on the whitelist (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist)